# Unable to create external item

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to create an external item using

```
await graphClient.Connections[connectionId].Items[item.Id].Request().PutAsync(item);
```

by sending the following:

```
    {
  "properties": {
    "ticketTitle": "title of the item",
    "priority": "high",
    "assignee": "someone@somewhere.com",
    "additionalData": null,
    "@odata.type": null
  },
  "acl": [
    {
      "accessType": 1,
      "identitySource": "External",
      "type": 1,
      "value": "SomeUser",
      "additionalData": null,
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.acl"
    }
  ],
  "content": {
    "type": 1,
    "value": "Some value",
    "additionalData": null,
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.externalItemContent"
  },
  "id": "ABCD12345",
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.externalItem",
  "additionalData": null
}
```

But I get the following response back:

```
Code: UnknownError
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2021-03-24T22:31:31
        request-id: fc55be4e-c84d-4376-8305-d0e33f2729a0
        client-request-id: fc55be4e-c84d-4376-8305-d0e33f2729a0
ClientRequestId: fc55be4e-c84d-4376-8305-d0e33f2729a0
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried not sending AdditionalData or ODataType in Properties, but same error

Comment: Dumped the URL that the graph client is using. It is missing "external" in it (after the beta and before connections):

https://graph.microsoft.com:443/beta/connections/WestKMConnector/items/ABCD12345

The creation of the external item is working from PowerShell since I am using the full URL

https://graph.microsoft.com:443/beta/external/connections/WestKMConnector/items/ABCD12345

Is this a bug in Graph Client SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Graph SDK beta. Gory details at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/260 - but essentially I monitored the network traffic and noticed that no PUT calls to the Graph API. The request url that the Graph SDK beta is using is missing "external" in between 'beta' and 'connections' - so instead of using 'beta/external/connections' it was using 'beta/connections'

Aaaaaargh. (and that is why it is called beta, I suppose).

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to fix the path in the Graph SDK beta - so used a hack for now. 

So for those of you who are blocked, you change use C# reflection to update the read-only RequestUrl property. 

`var externalItemRequest = graphClient.Connections[connectionId].Items[item.Id].Request();
var requestUrl = externalItemRequest.RequestUrl;              externalItemRequest.GetType().GetProperty("RequestUrl").SetValue(externalItemRequest, requestUrl.Replace("connections", "external/connections"));`

Comment: This turned out to be a doc bug actually. It has to be `var externalItemRequest = graphClient.External.Connections[connectionId].Items[itemId].Request()`. The sample code in the documentation was missing **External**

I issued a PR and it got accepted as well. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/12175